# Does AWS Elasticsearch Supports force zoneawareness?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, aws-elasticsearch

Does AWS Elasticsearch Supports force zoneawareness
“forced awareness“  functionality is available in Elastic Cloud service.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you create a new cluster, you can pick whether the cluster should be deployed in multiple availability zones or not (usually when creating production cluster).

When you do so, AWS takes care of setting up [zone awareness](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-multiaz) for you and properly distributes everything so as to minimize service disruptions. You shouldn't need to have to do it yourself and there aren't a million ways to do it properly anyway.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as per the elastic documentation the Forced Awareness has a different defination.

"To prevent a single location from being overloaded in the event of a failure, you can set cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force so no replicas are allocated until nodes are available in another location."

Comment: If you use 3 AZs instead of 2 that problem is alleviated. You should read the section titled "Availability Zone Disruptions"

Comment: I have opted for a 3AZ and 2 replicas with zone awareness option enabled. As per the documentation of the amazon elasticsearch seems like enabling zone awareness is the only option and aws handles it efficiently by routing the traffic to the nodes I guess it has been closely integrated with the loadbalancer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-multiaz

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks for the vaulable feedback and response to the question !